# Typecast JS variable to Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript, casting, jsdoc

I'm using Typescript and JSDOC in my JS project and I'm validating my code against the TS compiler.

The following code throws a TS validation error:

```
interface IBox {
    idx: number;
}

interface IBoxes { 
    get(idx?: number): IBox | IBox[];
}

class Box implements IBox {
    constructor() {
        this.idx = 0;
    }
}

class Boxes {
    constructor() { 
        this.boxes = [new Box(0)];
    }

    /**
     * @param {number} idx
     */
    get(idx) { 
        if (idx) {
            return this.boxes.find(b => b.idx === idx); 
        }

        return this.boxes;
    }

    /**
     * @param {IBox} value
     */
    set(value) {
        this.boxes.push(value);            
    }
}

const boxes = new Boxes();

/** @type {IBox} */
const box = boxes.get(0);

box.idx;    // Property "idx" does not exist on type "IBox" | "IBox[]"
            // Property 'idx' does not exist on type 'IBox[]

(box as IBox).idx; // Suppressing the error
```

I know that I can type cast in order to handle situations like this. But as this is a JS project,  how can I do this using plain old JS only, as it lacks the `as` keyword? Is there some way to make it work using some JSDOC property or something?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, how would you guarantee that `box` is an `IBox` and not an `IBox[]` or `undefined`?  Convince the compiler that it's safe to get the `idx` property and it will let you:

```
if (box) { 
  if ('idx' in box) {
    box.idx;  // okay, box is now recognized as IBox
  } else {
    box[0].idx; // okay, box is recognized as IBox[]
  }
} else {
  // no box
}
```

Hope that makes sense.  Good luck.